# How can I check if all variables meet the requirements to put data into file?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, fputcsv

I need to check if all variables meet the requirements if they do proceed with file handling.

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$s_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$tuition = $_POST['tuition'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];

//Checking for Errors
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    //Checking Values
    echo '<ul class="error">';
    if(strlen($fname)<2){
        echo '<li>'."First name must be 2 or more characters in length".'</li>';
    }
    if(strlen($lname)<3 || strlen($lname)>12){
        echo '<li>'."Last name must be between 3 and 12 characters in length".'</li>';
    }
    if(strlen($s_id)!=9){
        echo '<li>'."Student id must be exactly 9 characters in length".'</li>';
    }
    if($tuition < 2000 || $tuition > 10000){
        echo '<li>'."Tuition must be between 2000 and 10000".'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

This parts work as it should it reports what errors have been encountered. Following this I need to make sure that all values are correct if they are output the success message and put data into file.

```
//Success
    if($fname == true && $lname == true && $s_id == true && $tuition == true){
        echo '<ul class="success">';
        echo '<li>'."Payment Successful!".'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';

        //File Handling
        $line = array($fname, $lname, $s_id, $tuition, $payment); //Creates a line to append to the file.
        $handle = fopen("log.txt", "a+"); //Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file.
        fputcsv($handle, $line); //Puts the values into the file.
        fclose($handle); //Close the file.
    }
}
```

I'm having problem checking if all variable meet the requirements I'm using `if($fname == true && $lname == true && $s_id == true && $tuition == true)`, but it seems to go though even with errors. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a flag at the begining of your script `$success = true;` and then, inside all of your error condition add `$success = false;`...then at the end instead of your `if($fname == true && $lname == true && $s_id == true && $tuition == true){`, you now just use `if($success){`

Comment: `$s_id = '1'; var_dump($s_id == true);`

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks. Just another quick question, is the format okay or would it be better to separate HTML from PHP?

Comment: Since you are using it this way, just keep with this way of coding until you master it...then slowly move to an mvc framework like `CodeIgniter`...and, another way to improve your code is avoid to use multiple `echo` statements...better create a `$errorMessage = ""` variable and inside every condition you just use string concatenation...and echo the variable at the end, just one time `echo $errorMessage;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be an approach like this:

```
$problems = [];
if(strlen($fname)<2){
    $problems[] = "First name must be 2 or more characters in length";
}
if(strlen($lname)<3 || strlen($lname)>12){
    $problems[] = "Last name must be between 3 and 12 characters in length";
}
if(strlen($s_id)!=9){
    $problems[] = "Student id must be exactly 9 characters in length";
}
if($tuition < 2000 || $tuition > 10000){
    $problems[] = "Tuition must be between 2000 and 10000";
}

if (count($problems)) {
    echo '<ul class="error">';
    foreach ($problems as $problem) {
        echo '<li>'.$problem.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
if (empty($problems)) {
    // Success action here
}
```

That would make a list of all problems, print them if there are problems, and do the success action if there are no problems.

When you'd use a framework, printing the list would be done in a separate file called a "view", which would separate the html from the validation logic even further.

**Edit:** "it seems to go though even with errors. What exactly am I doing wrong?"

In this case, I'd argue you're not the only one doing something wrong. If I were PHP, I'd do the opposite: not letting anything through, even without errors.
Here's what happens:

- Let's say $fname is "E". That's not valid input.
- You ask PHP if $fname is true. That means asking if "E" is true.
- PHP argues that "E" seems true enough.

A similar thing happens for all of the parameters. Only a completely empty $fname is denied. For the tuition, PHP only denies free courses.

The reason this happens is because PHP is ["weak typed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing#Implicit_type_conversions_and_%22type_punning%22).

Most other languages would simply conclude that "E" is not exactly the same as true, and therefore deny the input. Then again, they would also conclude that "real_file_name.txt" is not exactly the same as true, and also deny the input you'd consider valid.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it earlier, but your example is more optimal them what I've done. I'll try to do it this way later.

Answer (score 0):

i advise you to work with `isset(var)` example of the code and make var `$valid` to check if conditions are true , i hope this could helps you  :

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$s_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$tuition = $_POST['tuition'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$valid="";

if (isset($fname, $lname, $s_id, $tuition, $payment)) {
    $valid="1";
    echo '<ul class="error">';
    if(strlen($fname)<2){
        echo '<li>'."First name must be 2 or more characters in length".'</li>';
        $valid="0";
    }
    if(strlen($lname)<3 || strlen($lname)>12){
        echo '<li>'."Last name must be between 3 and 12 characters in length".'</li>';
        $valid="0";
    }
    if(strlen($s_id)!=9){
        echo '<li>'."Student id must be exactly 9 characters in length".'</li>';
        $valid="0";
    }
    if($tuition < 2000 || $tuition > 10000){
        echo '<li>'."Tuition must be between 2000 and 10000".'</li>';
        $valid="0";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
if ($valid == "1") {
    echo '<ul class="success">';
    echo '<li>'."Payment Successful!".'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    $line = array($fname, $lname, $s_id, $tuition, $payment);
    $handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    fwrite($handle, $line);
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```